# The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've seen similar questions that were asked in regards to this but my problem is a little different in that I'm keeping my application modular so I have defined the following method in a different dart file(Simply a class, not a widget):

```
Future getProfile() async {
return await usersCollection.doc(uid).get().then<dynamic>((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
  print(snapshot.data()['name']);
  if(snapshot.data()['name'] == null){
    print("No name exists");
  }
  else {
    return snapshot.data()['name'];
  }
});
```

And I'm trying to use it's value on my home widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carpoolapp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:carpoolapp/services/database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  DatabaseService db = DatabaseService(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Signed in'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          elevation: 0.0, //no drop shadow
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _auth.signOutUser();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: Text('logout')),
          ],
        ),
        body: Text(db.getProfile()), // Error is here
        //body: UserTile(user: FirebaseAuth.instance().getCurrentUser()),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I go about making this work without sacrificing the modularity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By seeing

`The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'`

this and

`Text(db.getProfile())`

the issue is `db.getProfile()` is an `async` method. That's why its telling Future can't be assigned to `String` since Text widget data key is of type `String` not `Future<String>`.

You can use `FutureBuilder` in the body and use the snapshot in the Text which will have the `String` value.

Comment: It worked! Awesome, I forgot about FutureBuilder().

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to @Pradyot Prakash's answer with some actual code:

Use the following code snippet as an example to achieve the modularity

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(

           future: getProfile() //  Your future function here

        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
          return Text(data['name']); // Your valid data here
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```