# The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this issue:

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

My code:

```
CupertinoButton(
          child: Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () async {
            print("- start customer creation -. ");

            if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {
              await firebase.newCustomerSetup(
                  email: _emailController.text, name: input, companyID: FirebaseController().getCompanyID()); 
              setState(() {});

              //UpdateListViewBuilder
            }
          },
        ),

Future getCompanyID() async{
    var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Company")
        .doc(firebaseUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      return value.data()!["companyID"];
    });

  }
```

Could I get and paste the Company ID without a Future Builder ??

The situation is the following: I have a software for company and for their customers. Companies can create a customer profile in the software (register them and customer will get an access E-Mail) and the customer will be shown in a ListView from the company's side.

My issue is, that every new registered Company can see all customers in the ListView (from other Companies too) because all will be paste in one collection. My solution is, that every Company will get an ID and the ID will be paste in the customer collection too after the Company registered a new customer. Then only where CustomerID == CompanyID, the customer will be shown in the right Company's profile (ListView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CupertinoButton(
          child: Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () async {
            print("- start customer creation home-. ");

            String companyID = await firebase.getCompanyID();
            await firebase.newCustomerSetup(
                email: _emailController.text, name: input, CompanyID:  companyID);

            print("- end customer creation home-. ");
          },
        ),

class FirebaseController {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore base = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late FirebaseApp app;

  Future<String> getCompanyID() async {
    var firebaseUser = auth.currentUser;
    String companyID = await base
        .collection("Company")
        .doc(firebaseUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.data()!["companyID"];
    });
    return companyID;
  }

newCustomerSetup(
      {required String email,
      required String name,
      required String companyID}) async {
    String password = generateRandomString(16);
    base.collection("tempUser").add({
      "email": email,
      "name": name,
      "companyID": companyID,
      "password": password,
    });
  }
    }
```

The fail was that the current user (company login) gets override when you register a new customer (with createUserWithEmailandPassword). So now the software create a document in Firestore and Firestore functions is handling the customer register, set a random password, the companyID and send an invite Email with password to the Costumer. Then Firebase rules handle that only the costumers with the same ID then the company will be shown in the ListView in the company software.

It was complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `await` before `FirebaseController().getCompanyID()`

Comment: Was not the complete solution but very helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: @niklasknuf have you found a final solution for that? If so, could you please add it as an answer? You may also check this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65508151/the-argument-type-futuredynamic-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-str) which could be of help.